# How do you embed variable in a variable in Jinja2?

Tags: jinja2

I pass in a value to my jinja2 template called "key". "Key" is a string like "user_id" or "birthdate". "key" is also a dictionary key. You would access it like {{key}} in jinja2. However, I want to access the value of "key" in a dictionary. "item" is an array of dictionaries. I want to do something like {{item.{{key}}}}, but this isn't proper syntax. How should I do this?

Comment: It should be `{{ var_name_you_pass.key_which_you_want }}`

Comment: that will give me the string literal

Answer (score 0):

Assuming item is a list, you should access the offset in the list that you want (e.g. if you want offset of x, use item[x]) which would then be a dictionary. At that point you can use the dictionary .get() syntax:

```
item[x].get(key)
```

Comment: i dont think that syntax exists in jinja2.

Comment: Which syntax? The list offset I think does, but you may have to use the double curly brace, such as: {{item[x].get(key)}}. May be wrong on the list access, but .get definitely exists.

Comment: Here is copy and paste from python 2.7.9 with Jinja2==2.7.2:

>>> jinja2.Template("{{x[1].get('foo')}}").render(x=[{'foo': 'baz'}, {'foo': 'bar'}])
u'bar'